# How to use multiple scripts in ElasticSearch should?

Tags: elasticsearch

How to use multiple scripts in ElasticSearch should

Here is the sample data

```json
{
    "hits": {
        "total": {
            "value": 3,
            "relation": "eq"
        },
        "hits": [
            {
                "_source": {
                    "type": 2,
                    "size": 11,
                    "name": "haha",
                    "length": 18
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "type": 2,
                    "size": 13,
                    "name": "haha",
                    "length": 17
                }
            },
            {
                "_source": {
                    "type": 2,
                    "size": 13,
                    "name": "hehe",
                    "length": 17
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

It looks like this.

```json
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {
                        "type": 2
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "should": [
                            {
                                "script": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "inline": "doc['size'].value == 11",
                                        "lang": "painless"
                                    }
                                }
                            },
                            {
                                "script": {
                                    "script": {
                                        "inline": "doc['type'].value + doc['size'].value == 15",
                                        "lang": "painless"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting the following error.
I don't understand why, I only use one of the scripts and they all work fine, do you know what is the reason?

```json
{
    "error": {
        "root_cause": [
            {
                "type": "script_exception",
                "reason": "runtime error",
                "script_stack": [
                    "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.throwIfEmpty(ScriptDocValues.java:73)",
                    "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs.get(ScriptDocValues.java:118)",
                    "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:113)",
                    "doc['size'].value == 11",
                    "           ^---- HERE"
                ],
                "script": "doc['size'].value == 11",
                "lang": "painless",
                "position": {
                    "offset": 11,
                    "start": 0,
                    "end": 23
                }
            }
        ],
        "type": "search_phase_execution_exception",
        "reason": "all shards failed",
        "phase": "query",
        "grouped": true,
        "failed_shards": [
            {
                "shard": 0,
                "index": "my-test",
                "node": "O9NpQOHXSNqELJwzBf5r0w",
                "reason": {
                    "type": "script_exception",
                    "reason": "runtime error",
                    "script_stack": [
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues.throwIfEmpty(ScriptDocValues.java:73)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs.get(ScriptDocValues.java:118)",
                        "org.elasticsearch.index.fielddata.ScriptDocValues$Longs.getValue(ScriptDocValues.java:113)",
                        "doc['size'].value == 11",
                        "           ^---- HERE"
                    ],
                    "script": "doc['size'].value == 11",
                    "lang": "painless",
                    "position": {
                        "offset": 11,
                        "start": 0,
                        "end": 23
                    },
                    "caused_by": {
                        "type": "illegal_state_exception",
                        "reason": "A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[<field>].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "status": 400
}
```

I want to use multiple scripts inside should, but I don't know how to use it, can you tell me?

Comment: please add sample document

Comment: Above query looks fine. What is the error you are getting?

Comment: That's the typical error for a document that doesn't have a `size` field with a valid value.

Answer (score 2):

That's the typical error for a document that doesn't have a `size` field with a valid value.

> A document doesn't have a value for a field! Use doc[].size()==0 to check if a document is missing a field!

If you can't guarantee that all documents have this field, you need to test for the existence of the field before using it:

```
 "inline": "doc['size'].size() > 0 ? doc['size'].value == 11 : false",
```

Besides, this simple script can be replaced with a term query and is much more performant:

```
{
    "term": {
         "size": 11
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to use multiple scripts in such a way that this effect is achieved
Example: (a && b) || (a && c) || (a && d)

Comment: Does my answer above fix the error you get?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, your answer can solve the above problem, but I'd rather know how to achieve this by using multiple scripts

Comment: My answer solves the script error in your original question, so this should be considered answered. As for your other need ((a && b) || (a && c) || (a && d)) you should ask a new question for it.